A difficult high school geometry problem involving cevian of a triangle.
I was asked a simple (I thought) question about geometry by a friend. After some time I was able to find a solution using trigonometry and algebra but my friend said there was a way to solve it using constructions and plane geometry.
I have tried many things including internet searches but can’t seem to find a proof.
Here’s the question:
Given a triangle ABC with angle A 60 degrees and angle B 40 degrees, extend side BC through C. Now create triangle DAB such that DC is congruent to AB. What is the angle measure of angle ADB?
This is better in diagram form.

Now by the definition we gave, there should be solutions for acute all acute triangles but will be potentially harder.
The only clue I have is that you can extend AC to Z and create equilateral triangle ABZ to help.
Thanks for reading this question! It’s my first time here so sorry if the formatting and other things are wrong.
Also the answer seems to be 30 degrees.

First, let's construct an equilateral triangle $ΔAXB$ on the side $AB$.
Then we will construct a point $Y$ on $CB$ such that $∠YAB = ∠YBA = 40°$.

Now we can do some angle chasing to conclude that $∠CYA = 80°$ and $∠YCA = 80°$. That means that $ΔCAY$ is isosceles, and $AC = AY$. But $ΔAYB$ is isosceles, too, because $∠YAB = ∠YBA = 40°$. This means that $AC = AY = YB$.
Because $ΔAXB$ is equilateral, $XB = AB = CD$, $∠XBA = 60°$, and $∠XBY = 100°$. Also, $∠DCA = 100°$.
Niw let's use everything we've proven by now to prove that $ΔYBX = ΔACD$:
$$∠YBX = ∠ACD = 100°;$$$$DC = BX;$$$$AC = BY.$$
This means that, by the SAS congruency, $ΔACD = ΔYBX$, and $∠ADC = ∠YXB$, and, since $YAXB$ is a kite, $XY$ is an angle bisector of $∠AXB$, and $∠YXB = ∠ADC = 30°$.

Thank you! This is very insightful.  I found a similar approach except by creating a equilateral triangle ACE extending out of AC to E and then proving triangle DEB was isosceles, this proved ADE isosceles with angles 50,50,80

Extend $AC$ to $O$ to form the equilateral $AOB$ and extend $BO=OE$ to form the circumdiameter of $\triangle{EAB}$, in which $\angle{BEA}=30^\circ$. If $D$ lies on the circumcircle, $\angle{BEA}=\angle{BDA}=30 ^\circ$, and we are done.
To prove that $D$ is on the circumcircle, translate $DC$ by $CO$ to $FO$, where $F$ must be on the circumcircle since $CD=AB=R$. Since $\angle{FOE}=\angle{CBO}$ due to parallel lines, $\angle{FOE}=20^\circ$. If we reflect $\angle{EOF}$ about ${OF}$ to ${FOD'}$ (not shown) we subtend another $20^\circ$, with ${OD'}=R$. Finally, translate ${OD'}$ by ${CO}$ exactly as before, and note that since positions $D$ and $F$ represent arcs $+10$ and $-10$ about the perpendicular bisector of $ACO$ (thin green line) that $DF$ is parallel to $ACO$ and thus $D'$ must arrive at exactly $F$ after this translation, proving that $D'$ coincides with $D$. Hence, $D$ lies on the circumcircle.


A simpler proof of $D$ lies on the circle: Let $D' = BD \cap \odot(O)$, then note that $\angle D'OC=\angle D'OA = 2\angle D'BA = 2\angle DBA = 80^\circ$. But also, $\angle D'CO = \angle DCO = 80^\circ$, hence $D'CO$ is isosceles. Thus $D'C = D'O = AB = DB \implies D=D'$.

@DS that works too, potato potahto to me, but you probably want AB=DC in the final step.

Yeah, it was a typo @RobinSparrow

To make things simpler I'm going to let the sides with the tick marks each have a length of 1.  Since the angles in a triangle add up to 180$^\circ$ (on a flat surface), $m\angle$ACB = 80$^\circ$, then use the Law of Sines:
$\frac{\overline{BC}}{\sin60^\circ} = \frac{1}{\sin80^\circ} \rightarrow \overline{BC}\sin80^\circ = \sin60^\circ \rightarrow |\overline{BC}| = \frac{\sin60^\circ}{\sin80^\circ} \approx .88$ .
$\frac{\overline{AC}}{\sin40^\circ} = \frac{1}{\sin80^\circ} \rightarrow \overline{AC}\sin80^\circ = \sin40^\circ \rightarrow |\overline{AC}| = \frac{\sin40^\circ}{\sin80^\circ} \approx .653$ .
Since $m\angle$ACB = 80$^\circ$, $m\angle$ACD = 100$^\circ$.  We can now use the Law of Cosines:
$|\overline{AD}| = \sqrt{|\overline{CD}|^2 + |\overline{AC}|^2 - 2|\overline{CD}||\overline{AC}|\cos\theta} = \sqrt{1^2 + \bigl(\frac{\sin40^\circ}{\sin80^\circ}\bigr)^2 - 2(1)\bigl(\frac{\sin40^\circ}{\sin80^\circ}\bigr)\cos100^\circ} \approx 1.2856$.
Then, use the Law of Sines again on $\triangle$DAB:
$\frac{|\overline{AD}|}{\sin40^\circ} = \frac{1}{\sin\angle\text{ADB}} \rightarrow \frac{1.2856}{\sin40^\circ} = \frac{1}{\sin\angle\text{ADB}} \rightarrow 1.2856\sin\angle\text{ADB} = \sin40^\circ \rightarrow \sin\angle\text{ADB} = \frac{\sin40^\circ}{1.2856} \rightarrow m\angle\text{ADB} = \arcsin\bigl(\frac{\sin40^\circ}{1.2856}\bigr) = \arcsin(.5) = 30^\circ$.

Did you read the question? Geometric solutions, not trigonometric solutions, is what OP is looking for.
